# How do i get an object name from its ID?

Tags: c#, object, identification

I have a class used for object's called `Person`. The class Person holds the values Name, Last_Name, Age and most importantly ID.

How do I grab something like Name or age using the ID? Code:

```
// Person Class    
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

    class Person
    {
        private static int currentID;
        protected int Age { get; set; }
        protected string Name { get; set; }
        protected string Name_Last { get; set; }
        protected int ID { get; set; }
        protected bool Teenager { get; set; }
        public Person()
        {
            Name = "Default";
            Name_Last = "Default";
            ID = GetNextID();
            Age = 0;
        }
        public Person(string name, int age)
        {
            this.Name = name;
            this.Name_Last = Name_Last;
            this.ID = GetNextID();
        }
        static Person()
        {
            currentID = 0;
        }
        protected int GetNextID()
        {
            return ++currentID;
        }
        public void Update(string name, int age, string LastName = "Default")
        {
            this.Name = name;
            this.Name_Last = LastName;
            this.Age = age;
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return String.Format("Name: {0},"+getIsLastNameDiscription(" Lastname: ", ",")+" Age: {1}, isTeenager: "+isTeenager()+", CurrentID: {2}", this.Name, this.Age, this.ID);
        }
        private bool isLastname()
        {
            if (this.Name_Last != "Default")
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
        private string getIsLastName()
        {
            if (this.isLastname())
                return this.Name_Last;
            else
                return "";
        }
        private string getIsLastNameDiscription(string Stuffix = "", string EndStuffix = "")
        {
            if (this.isLastname())
                return Stuffix+this.Name_Last+EndStuffix;
            else
                return "";
        }
        public string getIsTeenager(string TrueOutput = "true", string FalseOutput = "false")
        {
            if (this.isTeenager())
                return TrueOutput;
            else
                return FalseOutput;
        }
        public bool isTeenager()
        {
        if(this.Age >= 13 && Age <= 18)
        return true;
        else
        return false;
        }
        public string Discription()
        {
            return String.Format("{0} is {1} years old and he has the ID of {2}", this.Name,
                                                                                  this.Age,
                                                                                  this.ID);
        }
    }
```

---

```
// Program Class
class Program : Person
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Person Luke = new Person();
        Luke.Update("Luke", 15);
        Console.WriteLine(Luke.ToString());
        Person Daniel = new Person();
        Daniel.Update("Daniel", 14, "Jones");
        Console.WriteLine(Daniel.ToString());
        Person Aimee = new Person();
        Aimee.Update("Aimee", 18, "Jones");
        Console.WriteLine(Aimee.ToString());
        Person Will = new Person();
        Will.Update("William", 22, "Rae");
        Console.WriteLine(Will.ToString());

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to grab from where? list of `Person` or Database? or from a single `Person` object?

Comment: I don't a data base of objects, rather to grab the object from its ID

Comment: If you have the object you have already grabbed it.

Comment: What do you mean by *grab*? choose, select, hold, touch?

Comment: I think you are aware that we *choose*/*select* **thing** from a lot of **thing*s***. Now here I dont see **things**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You need store all persons, something like that:

```
class Program
{
    static List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        Person Luke = new Person();
        Luke.Update("Luke", 15);
        Console.WriteLine(Luke.ToString());
        Person Daniel = new Person();
        Daniel.Update("Daniel", 14, "Jones");
        Console.WriteLine(Daniel.ToString());
        Person Aimee = new Person();
        Aimee.Update("Aimee", 18, "Jones");
        Console.WriteLine(Aimee.ToString());
        Person Will = new Person();
        Will.Update("William", 22, "Rae");
        Console.WriteLine(Will.ToString());

        persons.Add(Luke);
        persons.Add(Daniel );
        persons.Add(Aimee );
        persons.Add(Will );

        var founded = FindPersonById("xxx-x-xxxxx");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }  
    static Person FindPersonById(int Id)
    {
        return persons.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ID == Id);
    }
}
```

Comment: return persons.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == Id); comes at an error at p.Id?

Comment: You need declare property ID of person class, public, and not protected.

Comment: If i understand you correctly, I'm renaming protected int ID to public?

Comment: Yes, you have to do, public int ID in class Person.

Comment: Thanks it worked! but to use the variables like name and age i must make them public.

Comment: Any way of making it so i cant change it outside of the class? Example i don't want: founded.age = 10;

Comment: You have change a setter private in properties . Example:                                                          public int Age { get; private set; }

Answer (score 0):

add your `Person` objects to a List and from that `list` get object using id

Comment: Can you show an example?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class PersonRepo
{
    static Dictionary<int, Person> people = new Dictionary<int, Person>();
    public void Upsert(Person P)
    {
        if (people.ContainsKey(P.ID))
            people[P.ID] = P;
        else
            people.Add(P.ID, P);
    }

    public Person Get(int ID)
    {
        if (!people.ContainsKey(ID))
            return null;

        return people[ID];
    }
}
```

Then in your main function you do

```
public static void Main()
{
    var people = new PersonRepo()

    Person Luke = new Person();
    Luke.Update("Luke", 15);
    people.Upsert(Luke.ID,Luke);


    Person Daniel = new Person();
    Daniel.Update("Daniel", 14, "Jones");
    people.Upsert(Daniel.ID,Daniel);


    Person Aimee = new Person();
    Aimee.Update("Aimee", 18, "Jones");
    people.Upsert(Daniel.ID,Daniel);


    Person Will = new Person();
    Will.Update("William", 22, "Rae");
    people.Upsert(Daniel.ID,Daniel);

    // To get the person by id you can do
    int id = 3;
    var person = people.Get(id)
    Console.WriteLine(person.ToString())

}
```

This has not seen a compiler so please excuse any typos

Comment: You are creating you own problem and solving it.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im I did not understand the comment, can you please clarify

Comment: I need it to grab the object by its ID. for example i would have something in the Person Class that will grab the object.

Comment: @SuryaPratap OP didn't specify he/she has any list of objects. he/she is not clarifying.

Comment: @user2595374 you need to understand that the person class is a template for data and not the store of data.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im yes, I assumed that part, My bad

Comment: @user2595374 you can loosely imagine the object to be the table structure in a database and the instance of the object (new Person()) to be the rows in the database, the list/dictionary is the physical table that contains the rows

Comment: I need something like getObject where i would pars in an ID and it would return an object.

Comment: I'm new to objects in general, sorry about that.

Comment: @Surya Pratap I understand how objects work in that way.

Comment: Person pers = Person.Get(2);

        Console.WriteLine(pers.ToString()); <--Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @user2595374 you should be using  people.Get(2) and not Person.Get(2)